# 3-way ANOVA to 2-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, experiment-design, biostatistics

I have an experimental design with 3 factors of 2 levels each, which are temperature (a1 & a2), pH(b1 & b2) and food (c1 & c2), so I first ran a 3-way anova. Since in 2x2x2 experimental design I'm not able to perform post-hoc tests, I thought I could transform my 2x2x2 into a 4x2 treating all the combinations of temperature and pH as levels of a new factor, named environmental condition, so I had a1b1 a2b1 a1b2 a2b2...

Is it correct or there's something I've been missing?

Comment: What is it you ultimately want to know about these data? What would the post hoc tests be for?

Comment: my first question is if factors have an effect (both single or interactive) on analyzed parameters, so I use factorial anova... my second question is which treatment differ.. since I represent analyzed parameters through histograms i will be glad to show differences between treatments, but 2x2x2 anova does not allow me to do this..

Comment: If you have only 2 levels in a factor & the factor is significant, the treatments that constitute that factor differ.